# The role of univalence in the homotopy interpretation of type theory

Tags: lo.logic, homotopy-type-theory

In Martin-Löf type theory with identity eliminator

$$
J :
\prod_{B:\prod_{x,y:A}(x=y)\to\mathcal{U}}\left(
\prod_{x:A}B(x,x,\mathrm{refl}_x)\to 
\prod_{x,y:A}\prod_{p:x=y}B(x,y,p)
\right)
$$

satisfying $J(B,b,x,x,\mathrm{refl}_x)=b(x)$ we can have terms $p:x=x$ that are not equal to $\mathrm{refl}_x$.

We can then interpret the $x:A$ as points of a space, and the terms of $x=y$ as the paths joining $x$ and $y$. The loops $p:x=x$ that are not $\mathrm{refl}_x$ are interpreted as non-contractible loops. Terms of type $p=_{x=y}q$ are homotopies between paths, etc.

Now, I have seen that the univalence axiom is of great importance in homotopy type theory, but I don't see how it enters in this discussion. The question is: does univalence have consequences in the homotopy interpretation of type theory?

If the answer is yes, what role does it play?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Whenever you’re looking at a logical system, there’s a tension between two main ways of studying it:

- axioms/theorems in the system show what the world it describes *must* look like;
- models show what the world it describes *can* look like.

The interpretation of types as spaces shows that the types of plain Martin-Löf type theory *can* look like homotopically non-trivial spaces (unlike e.g. the sets of ZF(C), which are always homotopically discrete).

However, in plain Martin-Löf type theory, you can’t prove that there *must* exist homotopically non-trivial types.  It’s consistent that every type “is a set”, in the sense of being homotopically discrete.  This follows from the fact that you can also model types as plain old sets, in ZF(C) or any similar theory.

**Univalence implies that there *must* exist homotopically non-trivial types.**  Specifically, once you add both univalence and higher inductive types, then (as shown in the HoTT book, and various papers on synthetic homotopy theory) you can reproduce many standard constructions of spaces from classical homotopy theory, and show that they behave how you’d expect them to in many ways: e.g. that the fundamental group of the circle is $\mathbb{Z}$, just to name the simplest non-trivial such fact.

So from the point of view of the homotopy interpretation of type theory, the rôle of univalence is ensuring that enough homotopically non-trivial types exist for the world to look like a reasonable homotopy-theoretic world.  One approach to making this precise is to say that univalence should force the universe (or a hierarchy of universes, or something) to be an *object classifier* (or classiying family, or something) in the sense of Lurie’s ∞-topos theory — though this idea hasn’t been made precise yet.

This isn’t the only rôle of univalence: it’s not Voevodsky’s original motivation, for example.  That was roughly, as I understand it, to allow more powerful and natural reasoning about how constructions respect equivalence, because pragmatically one often needs to use such reasoning when formalising mathematics in type theory. But it’s the essential rôle that univalence plays from the point of view of the homotopy-theoretic interpretation.

Comment: I would add that the univalence for a single universe alone is not enough to get a real homotopy theoretic feel: One can imagine a model where general type are groupoids, but small types are sets ($h$-sets) and the Universe is the groupoids of sets and isomorphisms between them. This will satisfies univalence but have almost no homotopy theoretic contents. This is really (as you pointed out) the interaction between higher inductive type and univalence which forces to have interesting homotopy theoretic content. Having a full hierarchy of universe all univalent also do the trick.

Comment: @SimonHenry: Yes, absolutely — “a univalent universe” means almost nothing until you specify what type-constructions you’re assuming the universe is closed under, and this is something people are often very vague about (as I was here).  To get a homotopically rich universe, you want closure under at least M-L’s original constructors, plus some HIT’s — e.g. pushouts is enough to go along way.  Or, as you say, a hierarchy — i.e. univalent universes that contain other univalent universes.

Comment: Specifically: if HITs exist and can eliminate into univalent universes, then the HITs are not in general sets; if a univalent universe *contains* a type with a nontrivial automorphism like bool or nat, then *it* is not a set; and Kraus and Sattler showed that the nth nested universe is not an n-type.  One univalent universe (of propositions only, i.e. a subobject classifier) can exist even if all types are sets.

Comment: Also, FWIW, one sense in which the universe is an object classifier is proven in section 4.8 of the book.

Comment: "because pragmatically one often needs..." Does that mean that univalence is strictly speaking not necessary for formalising what can be found in say UniMath library? It only makes proofs shorter?

Comment: I have a stupid question (it is good enough for a comment I hope): can we prove that there does not exist any model of ZFC interpreting sets as non-trivial spaces (I mean non-discrete) ?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold the idea is to be able to capture mathematics that is invariant under isomorphism or more generally equivalence and higher equivalence (VV was after all working at the 2- and 3-category level on the rather complicated results that starting giving him concerns regarding verification for correctness). Formal verification systems that are built on ZF, say, don't have this built in.

Comment: @MikeShulman: §4.8 of the HoTT Book develops how the univalent universe is an object classifier, in a type-theoretic sense that’s clearly somewhat analogous to the ∞-categorical sense of that term.  But it’s not making the connection with the ∞-categorical setting precise in any way, which is what I was meaning in the answer.

Comment: @PhilippeGaucher: there may well be models of ZF(C) where sets are interpreted as spaces in some non-trivial way; if you generalise to constructive set theories like IZF, there certainly are such models.  But there can’t be models where “sets are homotopically non-trivial spaces, and equality is path-spaces”, because the first-order logic formulation of all these set theories forces equality in them to be a “mere proposition”.

Comment: @DavidRoberts, but suppose we use MLTT and not ZF, is there a theorem at the 2- and 3- category level that we cannot state or prove without univalence?

Comment: @Michael clearly not, since, modulo size issues, ZF(C) is a foundation after all. The idea is to make the formalisation more 'natural'. If you know how Bourbaki tried to treat his concept of structure in (his version of) set theory, you can see how awkward it can get, and that's without formalisation.

Comment: @DavidRoberts thanks, but I'm still wondering about MLTT and _not_ ZF(C). So is MLTT without univalence also a foundation for mathematics?

Comment: @Michael sorry, got the wrong idea. I'm not sure, I don't know enough about plain MLTT.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold plain MLTT can be used as a foundation for mathematics, but it's a bit annoying because, among other things, it lacks propositional truncation, function extensionality, and propositional extensionality.  Thus, often people using it as a foundation are forced to build mathematics out of "setoids" rather than types.  For set-level mathematics, this is tedious and annoying but mostly works; but when you start doing higher-categorical mathematics, it gets problematic, and you start feeling forced towards a more HoTT-like approach.  (I hope this is a fair characterization.)

Comment: There are certainly theorems in HoTT about categories (and 2-categories and 3-categories) that we can't prove without univalence; see for instance chapter 9 of the book.